# Performance of stored procedure vs scalar-valued function in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am wondering about performance difference between stored procedure and scalar-valued function. For now i use mostly scalar-valued functions because i can use them inside other queries (and 99% of time they return 1 value anyway). 
But there are scalar-valued functions that I never use within other queries and usually i call them with simple SELECT dbo.somefunction (parameter) and that's it.

Would it be better from performance point of view to migrate them to stored procedure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scalar valued functions are recompiled every time they are called. This is because they cannot be included  in the plan cache created from the sql processed by the query optimizer/processor.

For cases where you only call the udf once, (as in `Select dbo.UDFName(params)` ) it really doesn't matter much, but if you use a scalar valued udf in a query that examines a million rows, the udf will be compiled one million times.  This will definitely be a performance hit.  There is a technique where (if the algorithm can be written in a set-based structure) that you can convert scalar UDFs into what are called table valued in-line udfs that return one row/one column tables... and these can be included in sql queries plan caches along with the rest of the sql, so  they are not subject to this performance hit...

Comment: Don't underestimate what Charles has stated. UDF's are great, but they can be a tremendous, and expected, performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

There are no absolutes here, the devil is in the details. The best approach is to test for a given situation by examining the query plan and statistics.

Also, whether the function is CLR or not can make a difference of several orders of magnitude.